# How to set up ToggleFlyoutMenuItems so that only 1 option can be toggled on at a time?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm currently working on building a UWP Application (Minesweeper) in Visual Studio 2019 for school, I created a little menu bar at the top and am using buttons for dropdown menus using MenuFlyout. For the most part, everything works fine, however, when a user wants to make a new game using the menu they need to select a difficulty setting (Easy, Medium, or Hard) however by default the user can turn any number of these off and on at the same time as opposed to only being able to have on checked at a time. Is there a way for me to set it so that when 1 is toggled on it automatically toggles the other 2 off if they aren't already off or is that something I would need to build in when setting up the EventHandler method?

```
<Button x:Name="GameMenuButton"
        Width="110"
        Height="40"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="Game"
        Background="#7f1c1c"
        FontSize="20"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Top">

    <Button.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="New Game"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Reset Board"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="View Mine Locations"/>

            <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>

            <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Easy"/>
            <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Medium"/>
            <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Hard"/>

            <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>

            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit"/>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

Currently how the menu can look depending on what the user toggles

[image]

-------------------VS---------------------

How the Menu Should look when the user toggles an item

[image]

It doesn't need to always be medium, if for some reason that was confusing someone, it just needs to only have 1 item selected at any given moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to set up ToggleFlyoutMenuItems so that only 1 option can be toggled on at a time?

You could bind ToggleMenuFlyoutItem IsChecked with bool value and change the other two when one was checked. Please refer the following.

**xaml**

```
<ToggleMenuFlyoutItem IsChecked="{x:Bind Easy, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="Easy" />
<ToggleMenuFlyoutItem IsChecked="{x:Bind Medium, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="Medium" />
<ToggleMenuFlyoutItem IsChecked="{x:Bind Hard, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="Hard" />
```

**Code**

````
public bool Hard
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(HardProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(HardProperty, value);

        if (value)
        {
            SetValue(MediumProperty, false);
            SetValue(EasyProperty, false);
        }
        else if(!value && !Medium && !Easy)
        {
            SetValue(HardProperty, true);
        }
    }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Hard.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty HardProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Hard", typeof(bool), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(false));

public bool Medium
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(MediumProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MediumProperty, value);

        if (value)
        {
            SetValue(EasyProperty, false);
            SetValue(HardProperty, false);
        }
        else if (!value && !Easy && !Hard)
        {
            SetValue(MediumProperty, true);
        }
    }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Medium.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty MediumProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Medium", typeof(bool), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(false));

public bool Easy
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(EasyProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(EasyProperty, value);

        if (value)
        {
            SetValue(MediumProperty, false);
            SetValue(HardProperty, false);
        }
        else if (!value && !Medium && !Hard)
        {
            SetValue(EasyProperty, true);
        }
    }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Easy.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty EasyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Easy", typeof(bool), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(true)); ```
````

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I do have a question though, underneath each property setter you have the OnPropertyChanged() method but I don't actually see an OnPropertyChanged() method with info in it, is the implication just that I would need to make one or is it in reference to something else?

Comment: Ok, I will add the code. For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth). And if the answer is helpful please consider accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, there is a RadioMenuFlyoutItem in WinUI which will do this out the box: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.radiomenuflyoutitem?view=winui-2.2